# How to read the column SqlDataReader

Tags: c#

I am working on my windows form applications. In this winform, I have a **checkListBox** which binded the data from my sql db. I am trying to match the checkListBox's checkedItem to my sql table column's text which is stored as a `nvarchar` data type. I ran the debug mode and found out that it skip the entire while loop when the program is executed. I have no idea why because the valuable name `items` did actually showed which checkbox in checkListBox is checked

This is my code.

```
foreach(var items in checkListBox1.CheckedItems){

    string query = "select * from my_table WHERE employeeName = '"+items+"'"

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConn);
    SqlDataReader dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while(dr.Read()){
        //read the column    
    }
}
```

Here is the screen Shot. I tried to fetch the chineseName in the column (don't worry about what it is lol)

[image]

Comment: you may want to do some reading about SQL injection.

Comment: You may need to add `checkedItems` to a `string` from the `foreach` with comma separated and you can use the `sql query` outside the `foreach` something like this: `select * from my_table where employeename in ('" + string_used_to_add_checkedItems + "');`

Comment: does your *query* build properly? What is the value of query variable, can you show that? I suspect that *items* is causing issue.

Comment: Does "var items" contain your expected value?check?

Comment: Yes. the var items displayed what is checked from the checkboxList. But the dr.Reader() HasRows is false

Comment: Try items.ToString() instead of just items in your sql query

Comment: no luck, it still say hasRow = false  :(

Comment: @DragonBorn What is `CheckedItems` property? What it contains?

Comment: Can you share you DB Table : my_table structure via a screenshot

Comment: Instead of employeeName shouldn't it be firstName ! There is no field called "EmployeeName"

Comment: sorry, I the code before I did it for just showing an example. It wasn't the actual case from my project in my actual code, I have it as select * from employee_table WHERE chineseName = '"items.ToString()"';

Comment: @Kamo, what do you mean by property? It is a checkListBox

Comment: Try selecting based upon firstName if the code works fine there then this could be a Chinese-English problem

Comment: @DragonBorn is this problem still ON?

Comment: @Amnesh, yes, it still on :(

Comment: @DragonBorn I have invited you to a discussion room.. join that room .. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90770/checklistbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code. You don't need to write your query in ForEach loop. And if you are expecting to get multiple values from your checklistbox then equalto = operator is not your friend, you would need to use IN operator. Now check below example.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string items = string.Empty;

    foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        if (items.Length == 0)
            items = item.ToString();
        else
            items = items + "," + item;               
    }

    //make myCommand object and open connection on your own
    myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConn); 

    string query = @'select distinct firstName, lastName, chineseName, teacherEmail, entryYear, leaveYear, userLoginId, ad.applicationId 
    from [teacher_detail] as td 
    LEFT JOIN[class_detail] as cd ON td.teacherId = cd.teacherId 
    LEFT JOIN[application_teacher] as at ON at.teacherId = td.teacherId 
    LEFT JOIN[application_detail] as ad ON at.applicationId = ad.applicationId 
    Where ad.applicationId = 2
    and chineseName in (@name)'

    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.nvarchar);
    myCommand.Parameters["@name"].Value = items;

    //now execute query

}
```

Comment: This code won't pass this test : Suppose I have a guy called harsh immediately after it I have a guy called vardhan ! Both of the rows are selected ! Now suppose there is a third guy somehwere in DB whose name is harshvardhan ! Even though his name is not selected/checked the data reader will erroneously store this row also in the result

Answer (score 0):

As Data type in database is nvarchar try it by modifying the following statement in your code

```
string query = "select * from my_table WHERE employeeName = '"+items+"'"
```

to

```
string query = "select * from my_table WHERE employeeName = N'"+items.ToString()+"'"
```

Prefix 'N' is used for the value to compare from checked item

Comment: At Ramesh, It said incorrect syntax near 'someName'

Comment: @DragonBorn I Tested it and working fine for me. I took a table with a column of type nvarchar, used a checkedlistbox and did the query same as you and `while(dr.read())` working fine for me.

Comment: @DragonBorn is your list box displaying chinese names or english names?

Comment: my listbox is displaying chinese names, but this is weird, I am not sure what is my problem. I will try it again

Comment: umm that is weird, I am not sure what is my problem

Comment: Within the query you used the column name in where clause as `Employee Name`. But the column name that contains chineese name is `chinesename`. is this a mistake in query so that no rows returned from table as condition becomes false?